# $q.all is resolving before the returns

Tags: jquery, angularjs, promise

The `$q.all` is resolving before either of its functions has resolved.

I'm uploading two files to azure blob storage using $.ajax (I couldn't get $http to work):

```
 function doPhotos (result, i)
    {
        var d = $q.defer();
        var requestData = new Uint8Array($scope.files[i].postArray);
        $.ajax({
            url: result.photos[i].imageUri,
            type: "PUT",
            data: requestData,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function (xhr)
            {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-content-type', $scope.files[i].type);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-meta-uploadvia', 'CORS Demo');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', requestData.length);
            },
            success: function (data, status)
            {
                d.resolve(data);

            },
            error: function (xhr, desc, err)
            {
                console.log('error uploading photo ' + desc);
                d.resolve(err);


            }
        });
        return d.promise;

    }
```

This is the function that sets up the `$q.all` and is being called on a `ng-click`:

```
$scope.createVotation = function () {
        services.photoset.create($scope.model).then(function (result) {
            $scope.model.id = result.id;
            var doPhotosArray= [];
            for (var i in result.photos) {
                doPhotosArray[i] = doPhotos(result, i);    
            }

            $q.all(doPhotosArray).then(function (data)
            {
                // this is being called almost immediately before the photos upload
                $scope.safeApply(function ()
                {
                    $scope.submitting = false;
                    $location.path('/vote/update/' + $scope.model.id);

                });
            });

        });
    }
};
```

html:

```
<button ng-click='createVotation()'>Create</button>
```

The `q.all->then` is being called before even the first `doPhoto` resolve is called.  I'm not sure if there is some issue with using jQuery's ajax but it is my understanding that `$q.all` should wait until both promises (in my case there are 2) are fulfilled before entering its `then`.

As an added twist, the photos **are** being uploaded so that is working, it is the `$q.all` that is not waiting.

Comment: Should work fine. See this demo that increments delay of 1/2 second to resolve 4 requests. http://plnkr.co/edit/Zawd6dBZh6FlRPD0gsrV?p=preview

Comment: Check out this plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/XpGMfak4hzTKic8R3wdR?p=preview   The q.all never resolves although both functions do.  Though a different issue than my original question not sure why it is behaving this way.  I tried it with and without a timeout to simulate a couple seconds.

Comment: very strange...is almost same concept as my demo....can't see why it won't fire

Comment: I swapped out the $.ajax for $http in my program and it behaves the same.  The q.all is called immediately.  I put a breakpoint in the success/resolve function of the ajax/http and it gets called a minute after the q.all runs (uploading a 1.5 mb file).

Comment: Been playing with this a while now....I can't explain why, but if I don't use `ng-clcik` and call `$apply()` after `$q.all()` in a jQuery click handler it works  http://plnkr.co/edit/mtGo2aAhqthNGEP7Wjjo?p=preview. Seems to have something to do with `ng-click` causing digest cycle. Might try moving this to a service

Comment: found another way using `ng-click`  .... `$timeout(function(){
      $q.all(promises).then(function(data){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research and thinking about the various comments from @charlietfl, the only way I could get the $q.all to work properly is do assign the function call to a variable and then push it into the array that is being passed to q.all.

```
for (var i in result.photos)
{
    var output = doPhotos(result, i);
    doPhotosArray.push(output);
}
```

The various examples that I used for reference seem to indicate that the code in my original question should work but doesn't.

Comment: I know this was in 2013, but the problem is:
`ajax call -> return promise at some point -> q.all`, so the promises may not even exit when you call `q.all`, I do not think `q.all` will wait, which can cause problems.
Ideally you want to pass only existing promises either as obj.p1, obj.p2, or array [p1, p2] which you then pass to `q.all`. Q all will wait for p1, p2 ... not for other ajax stuff that happened earlier.