# Q require("asap") and getting related data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, require, q

I am using q.js for the first time with Angular.js and I have some code below where I am trying to get related info on a foreign key (each Team object has a GroupId foreign key that links to a Group object) :

```
new Team().$getAll().then(function (data)
{
    angular.forEach(data.value, function(value, key) {

        // We create our own promise to return
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('http://mycloudapp.cloudapp.net/odata/Groups(' + value.GroupId + ')').then(function(group) {


            angular.forEach(group, function(value, key) {
                alert(value.GroupName);
            });

            //set the group here somehow?
           $scope.teams = data.value;

            // resolve the promise
            deferred.resolve(group);

        }, function getGroupError() { deferred.reject(); 

        });
    });


    });
```

When I run this code I get the error :

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined


var asap = require("asap");
```

I have tried adding require.js and asap.js but that does not help, what do I need to do in this situation?

Also, I have not yet got to the stage where I actually get the group info and add it to $scope.teams, can anybody help me out with what syntax I would use to do this?

Comment: angular has its own q implementation. just inject $q into your controller or service.  Otherwise you can just pit a regular HTML link to the q.js file.

Comment: Thanks, removing the q.js and injecting $q seems to prevent the error message.  But how would I add the Group (got from the foreign key) into $scope.teams?

Comment: I will add a little blurb as an answer.  It looks like you might need to use $q.all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, with angular you will probably want to use the built in promise service and inject `$q` into your controller/service.

Second, it seems you want to `resolve` a bunch of promises in a function and the `$q.all` is the way to go.  An example might be:

```
function myCtrl($q, $scope) {
 function getKey(groupId) {
    // We create our own promise to return
            var deferred = $q.defer();
               $http.get('http://mycloudapp.cloudapp.net/odata/Groups(' + groupId + ')').then(function(group) {
                // resolve the promise
                deferred.resolve(group);

            }, function getGroupError() { deferred.reject(); 

            });

        return defferred.promise;

    }


    new Team().$getAll().then(function (data)
    {
        promiseArray = [];

        angular.forEach(data.value, function(value, key) {
            var p = getKey(value);
            promiseArray.push(p);

        });

        $q.all(promiseArray).then(function (data) {
            // data will have an array of promises returned after all complete.
            $scope.teams = data;  // just depends exactly what you are doing.
        });

    }

}
```

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522104/q-all-is-resolving-before-the-returns) about this prior that might help.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use the version of Q built for use in a web browser. The version checked in on Github is in development and unstable, so be sure to grab the latest *release*, 0.9.7. See “Getting Started” on https://github.com/kriskowal/q