# simple promise queue: q.all resolving before deferred promises resolve

Tags: node.js, queue, promise, q

The next installment in my struggles to fully grasp promises...

I am trying to create a simple promise queue (with the long term goal of throttling queries on a database), which I can then use with Q.all() and Array.protoype.map().

(This seems to be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522104/q-all-is-resolving-before-the-returns), but I did not see a clear resolution there.)

Here is my simple framework:

```
var Q = require('q');

var queue = [];
var counter = 0;
var throttle = 2;  // i can do things at most two at a time

var addToQueue = function(data) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    queue.push({data: data, promise: deferred});
    processQueue();
    return(deferred.promise);
}

var processQueue = function() {
    if(queue.length > 0 && counter < throttle) {
       counter++;
       var item = queue.shift();
       setTimeout(function() {  // simulate long running async process
          console.log("Processed data item:" + item.data);
          item.promise.resolve();
          counter--;
          if(queue.length > 0 && counter < throttle) {
             processQueue(); // on to next item in queue
          }
       }, 1000);
    }
}

data = [1,2,3,4,5];
Q.all(data.map(addToQueue))
    .then(console.log("Why did get here before promises all fulfilled?"))
    .done(function() {
        console.log("Now we are really done with all the promises.");
    });
```

But, as implied above, the "then" gets called immediately, and only the "done" is deferred until resolution of all promises.  I notice in the [api documentation](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference) that the only examples do indeed use .done() and not then().  So perhaps this is expected behavior?  The problem is that then I cannot chain additional actions.  In that case,  I would need to create another deferred promise and resolve it in the done function of Q.all as follows

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5];

var deferred = Q.defer();

deferred.promise
    .then(function() {
        console.log("All data processed and chained function called.");
    })  // could chain additional actions here as needed.

Q.all(data.map(addToQueue))
    .done(function() {
        console.log("Now we are really done with all the promises.");
        deferred.resolve();
    });
```

That works as desired, but the extra step makes me feel I must be missing something about how to properly employ Q.all().

Is there something wrong with my usage of Q.all(), or is the extra step above actually the right way to do this?

EDIT:

Tyrsius pointed out my argument to .then is not a reference to a function but is an immediately evaluating function (console.log(...)).  Here is how I should have done it:

```
Q.all(data.map(addToQueue))
    .then(function() { console.log("Ahhh...deferred execution as expected.")})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually your problem is with standard Javascript.

```
Q.all(data.map(addToQueue))
    .then(console.log("Why did get here before promises all fulfilled?"))
    .done(function() {
        console.log("Now we are really done with all the promises.");
    });
```

Look very closely at the second line. `Console.log` Is being evaulated immediately and being sent to `.then` as a parameter. This has nothing to do with promises, its just how javascript resolves function calls. You need this

```
Q.all(data.map(addToQueue))
        .then(function() { console.log("Why did get here before promises all fulfilled?")})
        .done(function() {
            console.log("Now we are really done with all the promises.");
        });
```

---

**EDIT**

If this is something you do a lot, you can make a function-returning function that works the way you want

```
function log(data) {
    return function() { console.log(data);}
}

Q.all(data.map(addToQueue))
        .then(log("Why did get here before promises all fulfilled?"))
        .done(function() {
            console.log("Now we are really done with all the promises.");
        });
```

Comment: aargh.  Burned twice in a row with immediate evaluation!  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Eric see my edit for a shorthand that might save you some headaches

Comment: You could also write `.then(console.log.bind(console, 'message'))`.